# Pivot table by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have faced one issue that am not able to solve. I am going to create pivot table by VBA but some reasons the code does not work. Here is the my source VBA code. When I run the code the pivot table will not be created. Any assumtions or any mistakes? Help. Thank you in advance

```
Sub Pivot()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTable").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTable"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("BOQ")


LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)

Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")




 Sheets("PivotTable").Select
 Sheets("PivotTable").Select
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Group")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
 End With
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Subgroup")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With
 With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Size")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("Quantity"), "Quantity ", xlSum
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("Total manhours"), "Total manhours ", _
    xlSum
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("Total machinery  hours"), _
    "Total machinery  hours ", xlSum
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("Total material cost/KZT"), _
    "Total material cost/KZT ", xlSum
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable").PivotFields("Total workprice"), "Total workprice ", _
    xlSum
 ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow


End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is masking the problem

Comment: You're creating the pivot table twice?

Comment: @Tim Williams  what do you mean about masking? Can you clarify you comment?

Comment: @Tim Williams no. I am not creating pivot table twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you call `CreatePivotTable` twice:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTable")

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")
```

Do this instead:

```
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                               SourceData:=PRange)

Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                                     TableName:="PivotTable")
```

Comment: does not work. The sheet "Pivot table" is empty. Code creates the new sheet "PivotTable", without any data. Only empty sheet